# i want the image swither in my app

Tags: android, imageswitcher

I want to insert the image swicther in my app so what should I do now?
this is aking for imageadapter so how can i implement it?
please help me..
thank u....

this is my code...

```
Integer pics[] = { R.drawable.amrapali1, R.drawable.defic1, R.drawable.hnsafal1, R.drawable.leela1, R.drawable.mitashi1, R.drawable.magnanimous1, R.drawable.moon1, R.drawable.netpeckers1, R.drawable.nggroup1, R.drawable.platinum1, R.drawable.shivalik1, R.drawable.trikon1 };

ImageSwitcher iSwitcher;


   iSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher);
    iSwitcher.setFactory(this);
    iSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in));
    iSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out));

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    });
```

Comment: or any other idea for this, in which images should slide and when i click on any image it should move to another activity this process should be done on every image....

Comment: Check out with my image adapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out with the below `ImageAdapter` class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c; 
        }

        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            ImageView iView = new ImageView(ctx);
            iView.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 150));
            return iView;
        }
    }
```

For more detailed understanding Go [HERE](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/imageswitcher.php)